# configuring multiple domains using virtual host with mod proxy in a single httpd instance

Tags: apache, virtualhost, httpd.conf, mod-proxy

I have an apache instance running three domains using name based virtual hosting and every domain has resources to reverse proxy them down to an application server. Application server is a JBoss running a since JVM instance (http://x.x.x.x:8080/)

The domains along with their resources are,

```
www.abc.com
 - alpha
www.def.com
 - beta
www.ghi.com
 - gamma
 - (root URL - no resource)
```

abd.com and def.com domains have one resource whereas ghi.com has two (root (/) and gamma).

this is how we have setup virtual hosting for three different domains. A sample for abc.com domain is below,

```
<VirtualHost *>
ServerName abc.com

            Header add Set-Cookie "ROUTEID=.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/alpha" env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED
            <Proxy balancer://mycluster1>
                        <LimitExcept POST GET>
                                order Allow,Deny
                                Deny from all
                        </LimitExcept>
                                BalancerMember http://x.x.x.x:8080 route=1 retry=0
                                BalancerMember http://x.x.x.x:8081 route=2 retry=0
                                ProxySet stickysession=ROUTEID
            </Proxy>
        ProxyPass /alpha balancer://mycluster4/alpha
        ProxyPassReverse /alpha balancer://mycluster4/alpha
</VirtualHost>
```

With all configuration in place when I try accessing these domains,

```
www.abc.com/alpha  --> works
www.def.com/beta   --> works

www.ghi.com/gamma  --> works
www.ghi.com/       --> works
```

since ghi.com domain has a root mapping (/) I am able to access resources of other domain through ghi.com and if I remove the root mapping, cross domain resource accessibility does not work.

```
www.ghi.com/alpha   --> works
www.ghi.com/beta    --> works
```

I do not want the resources of other domain to be accessed through ghi.com. I cannot remove root mapping from ghi.com virtual host configuration.

We have tried multiple configuration but none has worked out. 
I may sound bit non technical here which I apologize, but this is my problem statement and I am looking for for a fix.

---

update 1: configuration file after fix proposed by pandurang.

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
ServerName ghi.com

    Header add Set-Cookie "ROUTEID=.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/gamma " env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED
    Header add Set-Cookie "ROUTEID=.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/ " env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED
    <Proxy balancer://mycluster4>
                <LimitExcept POST GET>
                        order Allow,Deny
                        Deny from all
                </LimitExcept>
                        BalancerMember http://x.x.x.x:8080 route=1 retry=0
                        BalancerMember http://x.x.x.x:8081 route=2 retry=0
                        ProxySet stickysession=ROUTEID
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass /gamma balancer://mycluster4/gamma
    ProxyPassReverse /gamma balancer://mycluster4/gamma
    ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster4/
    ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster4/
    ProxyPass /alpha !
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below sequence and test.

```
ProxyPass /alpha !
ProxyPass /gamma balancer://mycluster4/gamma
ProxyPassReverse /gamma balancer://mycluster4/gamma
ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster4/
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster4/
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. Apparently it is with the sequence of how the resources are set to proxy which I missed in the first step.

Answer (score 1):

Create Three different Name-based VirtualHost and disable context(alpha and beta) in www.ghi.com.

```
<VirtualHost www.abc.com>
ServerName abc.com
Header add Set-Cookie "ROUTEID=.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/alpha" env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED
<Proxy balancer://mycluster1>
<LimitExcept POST GET>
order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</LimitExcept>
BalancerMember http://x.x.x.x:8080 route=1 retry=0
BalancerMember http://x.x.x.x:8081 route=2 retry=0
ProxySet stickysession=ROUTEID
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /alpha balancer://mycluster4/alpha
ProxyPassReverse /alpha balancer://mycluster4/alpha
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost www.def.com>
ServerName def.com
Header add Set-Cookie "ROUTEID=.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/beta" env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED
<Proxy balancer://mycluster1>
<LimitExcept POST GET>
order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</LimitExcept>
BalancerMember http://x.x.x.x:8080 route=1 retry=0
BalancerMember http://x.x.x.x:8081 route=2 retry=0
ProxySet stickysession=ROUTEID
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /beta balancer://mycluster4/beta
ProxyPassReverse /beta balancer://mycluster4/beta
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost www.ghi.com>
ServerName ghi.com
Header add Set-Cookie "ROUTEID=.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/" env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED
<Proxy balancer://mycluster1>
<LimitExcept POST GET>
order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</LimitExcept>
BalancerMember http://x.x.x.x:8080 route=1 retry=0
BalancerMember http://x.x.x.x:8081 route=2 retry=0
ProxySet stickysession=ROUTEID
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /alpha !
ProxyPass /beta !
ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster4/
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster4/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: hi, tried updating the config to block cross domain resources by adding ! following ProxyPass, but it hasn't worked. Still able to access alpha through ghi.com.

Comment: share your latest configuration file.

Comment: updated the question with modified config file. See update 1.