# How to do some url direct to one www folder , and other url to proxy pass in apache2

Tags: apache

I have following urls:

```
www.demo.com/a
www.demo.com/b
www.demo.com/c
www.demo.com/d
```

I want to direct a and b to directory. But I want to redirect c and d to proxy pass to some url.

I know how to do to proxypass or directory search. However, I am not able to find method to both .

I have following thing set up to convert http to https then proxy pass it.

```
UseCanonicalName On

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        ServerName demo.com
        ServerAlias demo.com


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =demo.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =demo.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        ServerName demo.com
        ServerAlias demo.com


        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8000/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8000/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/demo.com-0001/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/demo.com-0001/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Any one know how to change code to reflex that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option1:

You can use proxyPass for c and d.

```
ProxyPass /c http://127.0.0.1:8000/c
ProxyPassReverse /c http://127.0.0.1:8000/d
ProxyPass /d http://127.0.0.1:8000/d
ProxyPassReverse /d http://127.0.0.1:8000/d
```

In this case c and d will serve from ProxyPass and the remaining request will serve from Apache HTTP.

Option2:

```
ProxyPass /a !
ProxyPass /b !
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

This option will serve request a and b from Apache and the remaining request will serve from ProxyPass server.

You can refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61773746/configuring-multiple-domains-using-virtual-host-with-mod-proxy-in-a-single-httpd/61791036#61791036) for more information

Comment: How can this point to DocumentRoot for /a and /b. Do I need to handle all of different URLS in same VirtualHost or different ?

Comment: You can configure  DocumentRoot inside SSL VirtualHost.